# What's best practice for passing $scope-variable in function from template?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to pass a variable from angular template to a function like this:

```
<p ng-show="enabled('{{finalist.url}}') === 'novote'">
```

Is this appropriate?

Comment: what are you trying to acheive?

Comment: "I'm trying to pass a variable from angular template to a function"

Comment: `enabled(finalist.url) === 'novote'` should do the work, provided that `enabled` and `finalist` are defined on the `scope` of `<p>`. *I personally would prefer to encapsulate `enabled(finalist.url) === 'novote'` into its own function.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @artur grzesiak mentioned, I suggest that you don't put the logic in the view.
Better way to do it will be:

```
<p ng-show="isNovote">
```

And inside of your controller:

```
$scope.isNovote = enabled(finalist.url) === "novote";
```

For cleaner code, you should remove the usage of string literal "novote" for comparison, use some thing like this instead:

```
var voteOptions = {
       novote: "novote",
       ...other options
    }
```

And then use:
    `enabled(finalist.url) === voteOptions.novote`